# google maps api v2 android not works with device other than my

Tags: android, eclipse, api, android-maps-v2

I have create an app android with the Google Maps API v2. All works good when launch the app with eclipse. But when i export the app and i publish it in the google store, the people don't see the map. Why ?

Sorry for the english

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is related to your certificate and the API keys you need for the maps api to work. Google Maps requires a certificate for the API to run on the phone. You can read about generating the certificates you need [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). That the app runs fine when you are using it through eclipse sounds to me like you created an API certificate using your debug key and not your release key. The debug key, which is specific to your computer, would only work on your machine. If you want others to use the map in distribution you need [generate a release key](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html) that you use to sign your app for distrbution and then create a google maps certificate for that key. Once you have the API key for that certificate, you put that in the API_KEY section of your XML.

Comment: OK. I'm doing this. When the google store will publish my update, i'll say you the result.Thanks